# High frequency switching applications

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, high-frequency, solid-state-devices

I was reading that for high frequency switching applications with 
 semiconductors, the ratio of the electron to hole mobility should be high.

Why is it so? Is it a necessary condition always? Or just one of many possible 
 ones?

As per my basic understanding, for high switching applications, taking the 
 simplest case of a diode, the reverse recovery time should be dependent on the 
 time the minority carriers in each side of the junction take to return to the 
 opposite side on application of a reverse bias from a forward-biased state. 
 Now, a scenario like that would ideally want both the mobility of electrons and 
 holes to be high.

What I inferred from this condition is also that this necessitates that the 
 difference between the electron mobility and the hole mobility should be high 
 enough for the ratio to be appreciable.

Any insight on this would be helpful.

Comment: A hint could be, that electrons are faster than holes.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Mobility of electrons is higher than that of holes. Yet, why should we be concerned with the ratio of their mobilities?

Comment: Maybe to prevent fast recombination so electrons are available for conduction.

Comment: Well, fast recombination is needed in high switching applications, I believe. Its about switching, not conduction.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Now I am curious, too.

Comment: Haha, well, I believe this curiosity must be mitigated somehow.